# My python in virtual-env is 2.7 but the Django debug screen shows the system's 2.6.6

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

So inside of my virtual env, if I activate it and type `python`, version 2.7 is opened, as it should.

When an error arises in Django, it shows version 2.6 which is the system default. Here is what my Apache configuration looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/django-error-log
    Alias /static/ /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/mysite/mainapp/static/
    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/mysite:/var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/virtualenv-2.7>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/mysite:var/www/virutalenv-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

My wsgi.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

When I `service httpd restart`, this is what is put in the apache error logs:

```
[Mon Jan 19 20:19:03 2015] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 19 20:19:04 2015] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Mon Jan 19 20:19:04 2015] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Mon Jan 19 20:19:04 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Jan 19 20:19:04 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Jan 19 20:19:04 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Any idea why Django does not use 2.7 found in the virtual env?

Comment: Probably because your `mod_wsgi` is compiled against the system Python. Check the error log of Apache for startup messages.

Comment: I added the logs from apache error_log

Answer (score 0):

The `mod_wsgi` module is compiled against the system version of Python; the clue is in the startup message:

```
                           mod_wsgi library version
                           vvvvvvvvvvvv
Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.6 configured
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                        Python version
```

To fix this, you can either compile mod_wsgi against the version of Python you need, or use the [`WSGIPythonHome`](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonHome) configuration directive:

> Used to indicate to Python when it is initialised where its library
>   files are installed. This should be defined where the Python
>   executable is not in the PATH of the user that Apache runs as, or
>   where a system has multiple versions of Python installed in different
>   locations in the file system, especially different installations of
>   the same major/minor version, and the installation that Apache finds
>   in its PATH is not the desired one.
>
> **This directive can also be used to indicate a Python virtual
>   environment created using a tool such as virtualenv, to be used for
>   the whole of mod_wsgi.**

In your Apache configuration, add the following and then reload the server:

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/virtualenv-2.7/lib/python2.7
```

Comment: `Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 1023 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
WSGIPythonHome cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section
                                                       [FAILED]`

Comment: It is supported only at the server level.

Comment: Fixed that and the log is saying: `[notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
 [error] mod_wsgi (pid=15153): Unable to import 'site' module.`

Comment: That's because you have stuck your source code inside the same directory as your virtual environment; I only realized that after having a look at your paths. You should not play with the virtual environment; it is not where you are supposed to put your source code. Anyway, I edited the answer with what I hope is the correct path.

Comment: I did not edit anything to my knowledge, so not sure what you are getting at. I updated the httpd.conf and restarted and the messages are the same.

Comment: Update the configuration with the correct path to your virtual environment.

Comment: The virtual environment is at `/var/www/virtualenv-2.7`, where are you seeing otherwise?